# windows 10 cant access windows 7 shared access

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-10, permissions, sharing

i know this has been asked before, I have read the posts regarding it but couldnt resolve my issue.
I have a media server running windows 7, sharing various folders, these are fully accessible from other machines. i have 3 laptops running XP(yes i know lol), windows 7 and a macbook. Also, 3 desktop pcs running windows 7.
BUT a desktop running win 10 and the XP laptop that I have since upgraded to win 10 both show the media server in network devices but give me the same error when i try to connect.

Error : \server-pc is not accessible.You might not have permission to use this network resource. CContact admin of this server to find out if you have permissions.
Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer.

I have tried manually entering the server details in the windows credentials but still nothing.
All file sharing is enabled and i am now stuck.

TIA for any help.

Comment: forgot to say that when i access any other machine FROM the windows 10 one it asks for login details then allows access but for this one specific machine(windows 7 server) it doesn't ask for any login details just straight to error.

Comment: On my Windows 10 machine, though I do not see a remote share listed in the network, I can access using UNC notation, \\MACHINE_NAME\folder. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Can Windows 10 ping Windows 7 via IP and hostname?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to necro but this thread was the top result for me on Google.

I had the same problem: Win10 and Win7 machines in the same network and workgroup, both able to access other devices' SMB shares, but unable to access Win7 shares from the Win10 machine. Used to work fine when boths PC's were running Win7.

I solved this, but will be translating from a Dutch version of Windows.

On the Win7 PC, under network center > advanced sharing settings, under the applicable network type, (home or office for me) I set the following.

- Network detection on
- File and printer sharing on
- Public folder sharing off (irrelevant when using custom shares)
- Media streaming off (irrelevant)
- 128b encryption (irrelevant but recommended)
- Password protected sharing on
- User credentials instead of home group

I shared specific folders from the Win7 machine with a local user on that machine, meaning I had to enter that user's credentials on the Win10 machine. Apparently Win10 no longer requires the \MachineName\UserName format. It resulted in an error for me. Just the username sufficed.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: YES!
I've spent half an hour almost every day these past two weeks trying to make this work and finally this solved it! Password protected and using user credentials solved it. (Note you NEED a password on your user on the accessed computer or it won't work)

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that your Windows 7 shared file have proper shared permission on Windows 10 users.

If all is fine,enable NetBIOS over TCP/IP, turn off your Windows 10 Windows Firewall and antivirus.

Then make sure enable SMBv1.0 on both Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Afterwards try to change Windows 10 computer name and then restart the computer.